# How can I onto of a ring shape in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, user-interface, swiftui

I have a shape with an angle of 10 degrees I would like to add text on top of the shape. I have tried using `ZStack`, `Overlay` and the shape as background but it didn't work.
Below are samples of code what I tried:

```
//Background
Text("2")
    .background(Circle()
        .trim(from: 0.0, to: CGFloat(0.02702703))
        .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 35)
        .frame(width: 330, height: 330)
        .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: -90)))

//ZStack
ZStack{
    Circle()
        .trim(from: 0.0, to: CGFloat(0.02702703))
        .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 35)
        .frame(width: 330, height: 330)
        .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: -90))
    Text("2")
}

//Overlay
Circle()
    .trim(from: 0.0, to: CGFloat(0.02702703))
    .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 35)
    .overlay(Text("2"))
    .frame(width: 330, height: 330)
    .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: -90))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I got you right, your issue is that the `Text` is rotating in place.

The point is you have to size it as the `circle` to make it rotate as the `circle`.

```
ZStack{
    Circle()
        .trim(from: 0.0, to: CGFloat(0.02702703))
        .stroke(Color.red, lineWidth: 35)
        .frame(width: 330, height: 330)
    Text("2")
        .frame(width: 330 + 35,
               height: 300 + 35,
               alignment: .trailing)
}
.rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: -90))
```

Note that you can play around with the properties to match your needs since you didn't post an image of what you are actually trying to achieve.